# Changin span content (image url) to a image (display)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code: it's a SPAN or a DIV: with a ID I got the image url from a DB.

```
<span id="cover">http://server.com/images/file.png</span>
```

But I want to display that url in an Image.
Like this:

```
<img src="http://server.com/images/file.png" alt="">
```

How can i get it? it's possible with JavaScript/jQuery, etc.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why is this transformation necessary? Consider taking a step back and asking yourself why you can't just directly inject the url into an image tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a function below that takes a target element ID and replaces the element with an `<img>`, where the image `src` is taken from the target element text. Should work for `<span>` and `<div>` tags.

```js
function replaceImage(id) {
  var target = $("#" + id);
  var src = target.text();
  target.after('<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + src + '" />');
  target.remove();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  replaceImage("cover");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="cover">http://lorempixel.com/400/200</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the image tag inside the span or you can just place the id="cover" in the image as the span and image tag are both inline elements and behave similarly with regards to the layout.

```
<img id="cover" src="http://server.com/images/file.png" alt="">
```

or

```
<span id="cover">
 <a href="http://server.com/images/file.png">
   <img src="http://server.com/images/file.png" alt="">
 </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to display an image in that span that is not hosted locally?

```
<span id="cover">
    <a href="http://server.com/images/file.png">
        <img src="http://server.com/images/file.png" alt="">
    </a>
</span>
```

Do you want to add the image programmatically?

```
$('#cover > a').append('<img src="http://server.com/images/file.png" alt="">');
```

Comment: Just a thought. If you append the image to #cover. Wouldn't it append to #cover instead of the anchor tag?

Comment: I changed the first part at the end and forgot to update the jQuery selector. -Fixed